# Segmentation core dumped error in project

Tags: c

I keep on getting the error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

as I compile my C code in Codeblocks IDE linux.

I have browsed through and even tried the solutions to previous questions asked here on stackOverflow but to no avail.

Could someone please help.

Here is my code:

> > `

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Declaration of Global Variables */
char  message, chat ;
char user, pass, to, from;
int choice, response;
char filename[];
char buffer;


/* The API response Handler */
void fileHandler(int typ){

    /*
        typ = 0 for ordinary responses
        typ = 1 to get chat data
     */

     if( typ == 0 ){
        filename[13] = "response.chat";
     }else if(typ == 1){
        filename[9] = "chat.chat";
     }

    FILE *p;
    if( ( p=fopen(filename,p)!=NULL) )
        puts(chat);
    fclose(p);

}

/* The loged in user handler */
void logedIn(){

    printf("Welcome!\n\nPlease select an action:\n\t1.  Send Message\n\t2.    Read Messages\n\t3.   Delete Account");
    scanf("%d", choice);

    switch(choice){

        case 1:
        //Chat
            printf("Enter Recipient: ");
            scanf("%s", &to);
            printf("Enter Message: ");
            scanf("%s", &message);

            snprintf(buffer, 999, "php interface.php doChat %s %s %s", to, user, message );
            system( buffer );
            fileHandler(0);

        break;

        case 2:
        //read message
            snprintf(buffer, 999, "php interface.php readChat %s", user );
            system( buffer );
            fileHandler(1);
        break;

        case 3:
        //delete account
            snprintf(buffer, 999, "php interface.php delUser %s", user );
            system( buffer );
            fileHandler(0);
            abort();
        break;

        default:
            system("clear");
            logedIn();
        break;

    }

}


/* The user addition handler */
void addUser(){

    snprintf(buffer, 999, "php interface.php addUser %s %s", user, pass);
    system( buffer );
    fileHandler(0);

    printf("USER ADDED!");
    system("clear");
    main();

}

/* The login request handler */
void doLogin(){
    snprintf(buffer, 999, "php interface.php doLogin %s %s", user, pass);
    system( buffer );
    fileHandler(0);

    logedIn();

}

/*  The chat message send handler */
void doChat(){

}

/* The user delete handler */
void delUser(){
    snprintf(buffer, 999, "php interface.php delUser %s ", user);
    system( buffer );
    fileHandler(0);

    printf("USER DELETED!");
    system("clear");
    abort();
}


/* The chat render handler */

int main()
{

    printf("\t\t\t\tMyC CHAT\n\n\t\t\tSELECT AN ACTION:\n\t\t\t1.    Signup\n\t\t\t2.    Login\n\t\t\t3.     Exit\n\t\t\t:");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch ( choice ){

        case 1:
            /* Do a user signup */
            system("clear");
            printf("USER LOGIN");
            printf("\nEnter username :");
            scanf( "%s", &user );
            printf("\n\nEnter Password: ");
            scanf( "%s", &pass );

            addUser();

        break;

        case 2:
            /* Do a user login */
            system("clear");
            printf("USER LOGIN");
            printf("\nEnter username :");
            scanf( "%s", &user );
            printf("\n\nEnter Password: ");
            scanf( "%s", &pass );

            doLogin();

        break;

        case 3:
            abort();
            /* Exit */
        break;

        default:
            /* Give the user another chance */
            system("clear");
            main();
        break;

    }


}
```

`

Running on Ubuntu 14.04

Trying to implement a simple chat system using a php file that writes to a file.

Thank you.

Comment: You are saying the compiler is crashing or your app is crashing?

Comment: Could you please (at least try to) provide a minimal example?

Comment: How about a little bit debugging so you know in which lines the error is...

Comment: There are too many warnings in your code, you should turn on `-Wall` `-Wextra` `-Werror` if you are using gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code was mainly the poorly declared variables.
Especially the buffer variable which stores the file input.

The main error was however the somewhat "dynamically assigned" variable

> "filename" which was changed to "fil" and passed as an argument in the fileHandler function

```
 /* Declaration of Global Variables */
char  message, chat ;
char user, pass, to, from;
int choice, response;
char filename[];
char buffer;
```

After fidgeting for a whole night and reading through myriads of manuals [which are not so well done for greenhorns ]( Yeah, I'm obviously a noob! )

I tried many different things on the variables and came up with

```
int choice, resp;
char user[], pass[], to[], message[], from[], chat[9999], buffer[9999];
```

> Thanks Michel @ ueab for the support!!

The functional yet graphically and functionally gruesome application can be found at:

> https://github.com/ianmin2/chat

Answer (score 3):

You have lot of errors in your code, as @SSC suggested compile your code with all warnings. And use `gdb` or some other debugger to identify crash.

But to start with, in `main()` you have

```
scanf( "%s", &user );
...
scanf( "%s", &pass );
```

`user` and `pass` are `char` not `char *` nor `char` array. So when you read username it will overwrite memory. You need to use `char *` allocate memory appropriately or use `char` array.

Also there is

```
scanf("%d", choice);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
//----------^
```

Comment: Thank you. Had missed the &.  The program runs despite the errors and they all seem like gibberish